# how to select last day (max day) of each month using dax

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the following table:

[image]

I need to make a measure to return the values of "last day", but I cant use EOMONTH, because I have the current month, and the current month doesnt end yet, so, the last day of current month is today.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `EOMONTH` with a bit of extra logic:

```
LastDay =
    VAR CurrDate = MAX(Table1[Date])
    RETURN CALCULATE(MAX(Table1[Date]),
               FILTER(ALL(Table1),
                   Table1[Date] >  EOMONTH(CurrDate, -1) &&
                   Table1[Date] <= EOMONTH(CurrDate, 0)))
```

This takes the max of the dates you have that occur between the end of the previous month and the end of the current month.

Once you have this measure, you can use it to calculate the sum of `Value`:

```
Last Date Sum = CALCULATE(SUM(Table01[Value]),
                    FILTER(Table01, Table01[Date] = [LastDay]))
```